# Ionic back button whitout defaultHref

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this code :

```
<ion-back-button (click)="backClick()" *ngSwitchCase="1"></ion-back-button>
```

in my `backClick` I have :

```
this.back.emit({currentStep: 1});
```

The idea is that I want to emit an event when click on `ion-back-button`. And after that redirect to an url. But whitout `defaultHref` the arrow back is not displayed. From what I saw is not possible to do this kind of manipulations using `ion-back-button` ?

Thx in advancen abd sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend, There should be a defaultHref when you use the back button, If not, the icon will not be displayed, this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button) is the official documentation. (-;

An example:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons>
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/yourlink"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Your title</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
...
</ion-content>
```

Comment: anotthe solution didn't eist ?

Comment: I've never seen one, but you can use custom back button

Comment: If my solution is correct, please checkmark my answer